# Looking for a more concise JSP forwarding configuration in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, forwarding

In a normal Java weba app, if I put this in my servlet code the forwarding works:

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/something.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

But when I do this in the same servlet in a Spring 3.0 app I get a `404` even if I add this entry to my application context xml file:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/something.jsp**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="http" />
```

Instead I have to do this in Spring it seems:

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/something").forward(req, resp);
```

and add a mapping in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/something"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String something(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap model) {
    ...
    }
```

**But this is quite a significant detour to get a simple JSP forward to work.**

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

Set up the view resolver so the view names are based on the request URL:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Second, the servlet container chooses the mapping based on the longest path that matches.   So you can put this mapping in for your JSPs and it will be chosen over the /* mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Actually for Tomcat that's all you'll need since jsp is a servlet that exists out of the box.  For other containers you either need to find out the name of the JSP servlet or add a servlet definition like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Once those two things are in place then you don't need to do anything in your controllers except return a model.   It will automatically forward to the view from WEB-INF/pages based on the URL of your request.   In your example it would be /WEB-INF/pages/something.jsp.

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand your problem, but:

- `return "/something"` from a controller forwards to a jsp called `something.jsp` (if the most typical view resolver configuration is used)
- if you don't have a return value from a method, by default a jsp with the method name is looked up.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Yes, I'm aware of the points you made. However, I'm importing some servlets and JSPs from a non-SpringMVC app into my Spring MVC app and they contain syntax such as `getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/something.jsp").forward(req, resp);` which my app is not recognizing as a valid redirect even though I am putting the `something.jsp` where all of the other JSPs are stored in my Spring app.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, whatever you are able to do from a servlet you can do from within a Spring MVC controller (as at that point you're basically inside the `DispatcherServlet.service()`), so if you get a 404 this may be related to your servlet mapping. Is it possible that you mapped the Dispatcher servlet as /* ?

Separately (but more importantly, I'd say), Spring MVC (as basically any web framework) is supposed to hide the servlet infrastructure from you, therefore your need to use a RequestDispatcher and forward a request is not very clear to me.

To forward a request to a JSP, simply have that in a location that the ViewResolver knows about and just return "something" from the controller method -- as this has the exact same effect and is more "MVC-ish"...

Comment: "Is it possible that you mapped the Dispatcher servlet as /* ?" Yes. Didn't see that. Thanks.